# Getting error: data size bigger than max size for this type blob

Tags: hibernate, jpa, oracle10g, blob, max-size

I'm trying to update/save a blob in an oracle database, i'm keep getting this error: data size bigger than max size for this type, I've changed the driver and test and same error:

```
 getEntityManager().getTransaction().begin();
         Query q = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery("UPDATE TABLE SET IMAGE=? WHERE ID=?;
         q.setParameter(1, image);
         q.setParameter(2, 1);
         q.executeUpdate();
      getEntityManager().getTransaction().commit();
```

I am using Hibernate JPA.

Comment: What more do you want to know other than the obvious error message? If you would however, redirect the question towards Oracle/Hibernate/JPA after retagging/reframing, you are likely to get more help.

Comment: I get images from the database and replace it in another register just to check, but still same message. so it has to be something else than the size.

Answer (score 0):

Your image is larger than the maximum size for `blobs` in your database.

You can try compressing it, or using a different database. Other than that, not much you can do.

Comment: I've tested with a 5kb image, it's not that.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Can you post your CREATE TABLE statement for this table?